# Remove pipe symbols at the end generated by dataflow-ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a pipe delimited files with header and body. Header data has fewer columns than the body. In data flow, I am splitting header and body data and doing transformations on them and union transformation is applied to transformed header and body data. While joining both the data, I am getting additional pipes at the end of the header.

Source data will be like

Header1|id1

Header2|id2

1|Debashish|1500|30

2|Susmitha|1900|20

After doing transformations,

Header1|id1||

Header2|id2||

I need to remove the extra pipelines at the end of header, It should be same as source. How can I do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before copying the data from union transformation to the sink, you can concatenate all columns into a single column separated by pipe symbol and then trim the extra pipes available in the end of the data using **derived column activity**. I tried to repro this in my environment. Below are the detailed steps.

- A sample source file is taken as in below image.

[image]

- Source transformation is added with source dataset in dataflow activity.

[image]

- Then, a new column called `concat_column` is created using **derivedcolumn** transformation. Value for the column is given as
  `concat(coalesce({_col0_},''),'|',coalesce({_col1_},''),'|',coalesce({_col2_},''),'|',coalesce({_col3_},''))`

[image]

- Then again, a derived column transformation is added to remove the pipes from the data. Column2 is created and value is given as `rtrim(concat_column,'||')`.

[image]

- Results of **concat_column** and **column2** :
  [image]
- **Select transformation** is added only to select the column2
  [image]
- Sink transformation is added and for sink dataset, different delimiter is given (other than pipe symbol. Here no delimiter is used).

[image]

- After executing the pipeline, Output file has no pipe symbol at the end.

[image]